# TPanel Transparent

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

i need to use transparent tpanel in my form. Who can suggest me a good component for it, possibly free? If not is much long is possible post the code or some link about it? Thanks very much.
Marcello.

Comment: What is a transparent panel? Just take the panel out of the form and hey presto, you can't see it any more.

Comment: with XE2 every panel should be "transparent" by default,runtime themes active?

Comment: bummy: yes is active, i have checked. Hello david, sorry don't understood :(

Comment: I mean, don't use a panel at all.

Comment: What David is saying is that if you place your controls directly on the form (and not in a panel), then it will look just as if you have put them on a transparent panel (since, one might assume, a transparent panel is invisible). What David *really* is saying is that you should be more precise in your question. What exactly do you wish to achieve (what do you really mean by 'transparent panel')? Obviously you want it to be invisible in *some* sense while still being an ordinary panel in some other sense. Please tell us what 'senses' these are.

Comment: @David Heffernan yes your right that's wie wrote  "transparent" , which will work as long as no wincontrols except panels are used "under" then panel

Comment: I have two TPanel: first: TPanelMain and second: TPanelSub.  This TPanelSub is in TPanelMain. In TPanelMain i have setted background color, and i want set TPanelSub as transparent for inheredit the background of TPanelMain. Only this.

Comment: My point is that a transparent panel is invisible. So why don't you delete the sub-panel since you cannot see it.

Comment: David, i don't want a invisble tpanel, becouse in this TPanelSub i have other object (TEdit, TLabel etc) and want that it inheredit the background of TPanelMain as is. This TPanelSus need to be visible as TPanelMain, with the difference that in TPanelSub i want apply background of TPanelMain and then i need it as transparent.

Comment: What you describe is not transparency. When soemthing is transparent, you can see what is behind it. A transparent panel is invisible. So, I don't know what you want.

Comment: Ok david, if i have mistake word, excuse of course. But the concept it that. In TPanelMain i have setted a background color. In TPanelSub content in TPanelMain i have object (TEdit, TLabel etc) then i want that background of TPanelMain is in TPanelSub too. What i can to solve it?

Comment: Some options: 1. Remove sub panel and place edit, label controls on main panel. 2. Set background colour of sub panel. 3. Set ParentBackground property of sub-panel to be True.

Comment: I cant remove TSubPanel becouse i format the content in all form as a "Table" with more row and colums (maked with TPanel). I can try to set background in form directly and use TPanel but i need Always use more level to TPanel (one for row for example and three for colums). So i need other solution :( About backuground in TSubPanel, is solution that i using now, but effect is awfull, becouse background is a image and i have replied it in all TPanel.

Comment: Well, you could remove the sub panel. You just need to design a layout mechanism that isn't based on panels.

Comment: @NGLN Your deleted answer may solve Marcello's problem. It's just that your description of it being transparent wasn't quite accurate.

Comment: http://www.delphipraxis.net/39165-tpanel-transparent.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you could try downloading the Jedi component library, and look at the TjvTransparentPanel component, you can find it under the "Jv Additional" tab once you've installed that component library.

http://www.delphipages.com/forum/showthread.php?t=187137

Comment: Hello, thanks very much, i have installed it, but not fount TJvTransparentPanel but only TJvTransparentForm and TJvTransparentButton. Not exist the Jv Additional but only Jv Application, Forms and Jv Button with it.  I have installed latest version of jedi project vcl for delphi in xe2 version.

Comment: TJvTransparentPanel was merged with TJvPanel. You can use TJvPanel and set Transparent=True.

Comment: Thanks Abdreas i solved so too; i have found solution too with TAdvGroupBox setting borderstyle = bsnone and caption=''. transparent=true for default.

Comment: the solution could be nice BUT in order to get that control you have to install 100 others (the whole jedi lib).

Comment: With the latest Jedi library, 1) there's no longer a `TJvTransparentPanel` - it's just a `TJvPanel` with `Transparent` enabled, and 2) it's extremely buggy, has artifacts left behind, and the IDE goes crazy when I so much as place a button in it.

Answer (score 4):

Create a component and override the Paint method and a few other things: There are no borders or caption but it is a functional Panel. Any components inside will also need to be made transparent. Good luck.

```
unit PanelTransparent;


interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs,
  ExtCtrls;

type
  TPanelTransparent = class (TPanel)
  private
    procedure CnCtlColorStatic (var Msg: TWMCtlColorStatic); message CN_CTLCOLORSTATIC;
    procedure WmEraseBkgnd (var Msg: TWMEraseBkgnd); message WM_ERASEBKGND;
    procedure Paint; override;
  protected
    procedure CreateParams (var Params: TCreateParams); override;
  end;

procedure Register;


implementation

procedure Register;
  begin
    RegisterComponents ('AppMic', [TPanelTransparent]);
  end;

procedure TPanelTransparent.CreateParams (var Params: TCreateParams);
  begin
    inherited CreateParams(Params);
    Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle or WS_EX_TRANSPARENT;
  end;

procedure TPanelTransparent.WmEraseBkgnd(var Msg: TWMEraseBkgnd);
  begin
    Msg.Result := 1;
  end;

procedure TPanelTransparent.CnCtlColorStatic(var Msg: TWMCtlColorStatic);
  begin
    SetBKMode (Msg.ChildDC, TRANSPARENT);
    Msg.Result := GetStockObject (NULL_BRUSH);
  end;

procedure TPanelTransparent.Paint;
  begin
    SetBKMode (Handle, TRANSPARENT);
    //inherited;
  end;

end.
```

Comment: it simply doesn't work. the panel is transparent at design time but not at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use TBevel, and set the shape to bsSpacer, or bsBox or one of the lines?  You may find that already solves your problem if the nature of the border is not an issue.

Comment: But TBevel is not a control container.